# Hamcrest: dump current type and value

Tags: junit, hamcrest

I am writing test with usage of Java library Hamcrest and it's non-fluent API makes it impossible to reason about expression types when complex expression evolves, like:

```
.andExpect(JsonUnitResultMatchers.json()
    .matches(CoreMatchers.anyOf(CoreMatchers.allOf(
         JsonMatchers.jsonPartEquals("id", "123"),
         JsonMatchers.jsonPartEquals("name", "test")))))
```

Is there always TRUE matcher that dumps type & value of currently active expression? Like:

```
.andExpect(JsonUnitResultMatchers.json()
    .matches(CoreMatchers.anyOf(CoreMatchers.allOf(

         Slf4jMatcher.logType(),
         Slf4jMatcher.logTypeAndToString(),

         ConsumerMatcher.apply(System.out::println),

         JsonMatchers.jsonPartEquals("id", "123"),
         JsonMatchers.jsonPartEquals("name", "test")))))
```

I don't like to step into Hamcrest code with debugger. It is unproductive to delve into someones internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with ugly:

```
.andExpect(JsonUnitResultMatchers.json()
  .matches(Matchers.hasItem(CoreMatchers.allOf(
     new BaseMatcher() {
         @Override
         public boolean matches(Object item) {
             log.info("type: {}", item.getClass());
             log.info("toString: {}", item.toString());
             return true;
         }
         @Override
         public void describeTo(Description description) {}
     },
     JsonMatchers.jsonPartEquals("id", "123"),
     JsonMatchers.jsonPartEquals("name", "test")))))
```

I hope there are some funny DSL...